# Something Broke with Virtual Box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

So I was messing around with virtual box on my mac, I have windows 7 installed in the vm and I did `Command + c` and it resized (Scaled Mode) - (it was an experiement) - I didn't like it so I did `command + c` again and it broke. all I had was this tiny sliver of windows 7.

So I went and restarted windows 7 via the reset on the machine (vm machine) and it didnt help it was still a tiny sliver. So I tried entering full screen and scaled mode and nothing works. So I tried quitting VB and starting again and it still isn't working.

In other words How do I fix this? It seems that scaled mode is broken and as a resualt I cannot get a regular size of windows back:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtNP9.png]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press your 'Host' button + A to resize the Window.

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting the winkey+f (or command+f on a mac)

it should change to full screen mode, which will allow you to use it (or change configuration within the hosted machine)..

you can also try to scale the window size (from within mac or windows) sometimes it helps (scale the window - use the mouse on the edge of the VM screen on the mac, and try to change it size)